# How to perform numpy and sympy operations on integers that are raised to negative integer exponents

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I just haven't found a solution that satisfies me in what I'm trying to do. I am trying to test whether two sequences are equivalent using the python libraries Sympy and Numpy. I am getting an error message that says I cannot raise values to negative integer exponents. Would someone who is familiar with these math libraries help me correct my code to allow for this?

Here's my code so far:

```
import numpy
import sympy

n = sympy.symbols('n', integer=True)
a = numpy.arange(1, 100, dtype=float) #edited because of comment below
expr1 = (-1)**(n-1)*4**(n-1)/3**(n-2)
expr2 = 3*(-4/3)**(n-1)
f = sympy.lambdify(n, expr1, "numpy")
g = sympy.lambdify(n, expr2, "numpy")

# Calculate the arrays using the lambdified functions
array_f = f(a)
array_g = g(a)

# Check if the arrays are equal element-wise
if numpy.array_equal(array_f, array_g):
    print('True')
```

Comment: The array should be `arange(1, 100, dtype=float)`.

Comment: Thank you @OscarBenjamin for the comment, it removed the error message. It still won't print True though even though they are equivalent... Also, is there a way to write sympy.oo instead of 100 to test for all values of the sequence?

Comment: When you use floats, you should not check whether values are strictly equal, but only close to each other. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken . If you want exact results, then you need to manipulate a symbolic representation. Numpy does not support that. Only basic (rounded) floating-point numbers.

Comment: In code, @JérômeRichard is suggesting you do: `print(np.allclose(array_f, array_g))`.

Comment: For the numpy part, you may need to use complex arguments.

Comment: Thank you so much all of you, this code works. And thank you Jared for explaining what Jerome meant in what he said. That made my job a lot simpler. Best